# can we use != operator with outer join?

Tags: sql, database, outer-join

I wanted to ask which other operators are not being used along with outer join.

Comment: You can use any comparison operation in any join.  Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use not equal or equal operator in a join either it is an outer or not, provided that you will use it in the right place, like in a WHERE. There isn't any permission.